# Like box scroll bar

Tags: scroll, facebook-likebox

I've implemented an Iframe `Like box`, but the vertical scroll bar does not show. (The generated code set scrolling to no, but I've now changed it to yes, but still it does not work).

The code is as follows:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FChristopher-Carter-Veterinary-Surgery%2F332086710515idth=300&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true" scrolling="Yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:590px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The problem occurs with I/E but not with Safari, Firefox, Netscape or Chrome. It seems as if this is a Windows XP / IE8 issue, but if anybody knows differently, I'd be pleased to hear from them.

Comment: FYI, looks like this was submitted as a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/392793750816186?browse=search_51122072a302a2171117823

Answer (score 0):

Having style overflow:hidden; seems to me like a contradiction to scrolling=Yes.

At the risk of stating the obvious:
Have you tried:

```
overflow:scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the scrollbars in the **style** clause;

```
overflow: hidden;
```

However, it has the opposite effect, IE will correctly render as-is, but firefox etc will *not* render the scrollbars.  Fix that with;

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```